# Tires stick when turning after a car wash

Tags: tires, ford

I have a 2010 F-150 that just went through a car wash.  After the car wash, I immediately noticed that the turning feels reduced/impaired.  Specifically, when I have the steering wheel turned more than one full rotation, it feels like the the tires have gone flat.  I have visually inspected the tires multiple times and they appear to be fine.  I will be checking the pressure today after work.  I am curious as to what could have gone wrong or been broken during the wash.

Additional information:
The wash was an automatic wash with a hand dry and tire shine applied afterward.  It has been more that 24 hours since the wash and the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the tire feeling?  Slow speed / high speed?  Understeer?  Increased turning effort?  Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: Apparently one of the car wash employee accidentally put the truck in 4x4 high when cleaning the dash. I didn't notice the indicator and the locking diff was causing the change in handling.

Comment: Great - you should answer your own question.  Glad to hear that the truck isn't broken.

Comment: You may want to speak with a Ford Tech or someone more familiar with your truck's 4x4 system. I know some 4x4 systems can be damaged by being engaged on dry pavement, especially when turning. By your description, it sounds like yours may be that type, having the locker on when you aren't in a low traction situation.

Comment: ManiacZX - Thanks for the heads up.  I will have it checked out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently one of the car wash employee accidentally put the truck in 4x4 high when cleaning the dash. I didn't notice the indicator and the locking diff was causing the change in handling